# How to get Date between two Dates Django

Tags: django, django-views

I need to check is there any object exist for given time Interval? How can I do that?How can I translate this Mysql into Django:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `event_event` 
WHERE (startDate BETWEEN  "2010-10-1" AND  "2010-10-5")
   OR (endDate BETWEEN  "2010-10-1" AND  "2010-10-5")
```

I am currently using

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(startDate__range(datetime(2010,10,1),datetime(2010,10,5)))|Q(endDate__range(datetime(2010,10,1),datetime(2010,10,5))))
```

But I am not getting any object when I am using Django filter.Please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
print Event.objects.filter(Q(startDate__range(datetime(2010,10,1),datetime(2010,10,5)))|Q(endDate__range(datetime(2010,10,1),datetime(2010,10,5)))).query
```

And see what SQL it produces, it'll help you spot the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Do This:

```
Event.objects.filter(Q(startDate >= datetime(2010, 10, 1), startDate <= datetime(2010, 10, 5)) | Q(endDate >= datetime(2011, 10, 1), endDate <= datetime(2010, 10, 5)))
```